# Is password encryption required in frontend(client browser) for HTTPS protocol?

Tags: javascript, ssl, encryption, https, password-encryption

As title shown,

> Environment: password is already hash in database, and connection using HTTPS protocol

my question is simple, over the HTTPS, i saw some of the website using SSL, but also doing password encryption in frontend(client browser) when submit form.

> Is require?

In my mind, since website is using SSL. there is no need to encrypt password in frontend(client browser). Because whatever frontend(client browser) doing, hacker also can do the same way by using the library(client browser imported the javascript hashing algorithn) to encrypt and send the token. Even put a salt also point less, it just a extra steps for hacker to encrypt it.

Unless the salt is come from other way, not from the same source(page rendering from server). example: from mobile, and using otp as a salt then can resolve.

else i don't think encryption is useful in frontend(client browser).

Am i correct? or i missed out somethings......

Comment: Side note: you *may* be using "frontend" in unusual meaning - it is more common to uses "client/browser" -> front-end (server side rendering logic) -> backend (databases/service).

Comment: Any client-side encryption/decryption algorithm and keys would be publicly available, meaning an encrypted password could be decrypted much more easily (seconds) than when using private keys (years). If the connection is compromised there is little security gain other than minor annoyance for the sniffer. SSL does RSA encryption using private keys, you _should_ be able to assume an SSL connection can pass data (such as plaintext passwords) securely. **Still encrypt/hash your passwords**, just do it server-side.

Comment: @PaulS.  "Still encrypt/hash your passwords" are you means just let SSL doing encryption is enough?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, a **website** doesn't have any alternatives but to trust in the HTTPS/SSL connection. Whatever encryption you do on client side (browser) will be done in JavaScript and this script must first be sent to the client. A ManInTheMiddle can just do the same as your client does, or he can simply remove the whole script.

It is the same problem you have, when you and your colleague try to invent a secret language, while the bad guy is listening. If you do not already share a secret, this is impossible. An SSL certificate solves this problem, because the browsers have built in a list of root certificates, which will act as the *already shared secret*.

The situation is a bit different for **apps** with a client and a server part. There you could install a secret key with your app, and based on this *already shared secret* you can establish a secure connection.

So the short answer is: yes it is ok to send the password plaintext, as long as the connection is encrypted with HTTPS/SSL.

Answer (score 0):

No, You Don’t have to Encrypt Passwords before sending POST requests.

Actually, [TLS](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/learning/ssl/transport-layer-security-tls/) does that automatically for you. Even Google relies on this and doesn't encrypt.

More info [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzwkkZp5WcE)

Comment: if you could inline some info from the video, that would be great. see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587